# Cannot resolve symbol "GetController()" UE5

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I'm not really long into C++ Unreal Engine so my knowledge is not the biggest yet.
I want for a linetrace to use GetController(). Unfortunately always an error appears, looked into the documentation but found nothing. Also included the header whats declared in the documentation.

Someone know why dies GetController() appears as a error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGQZ4.png)

Comment: `GetController` is a member function of `APawn` - are you writing code in an `APawn` derived class?